# something wrong with this ERB code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's view code for showing all the blog posts. 
in the controller, @blogs = Blog.all
and there is a Blog model with a form getting input. 
I see nothing on the page though except a form which I put above this code.

```
<% @blogs.each do |post| %>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <h2>Title: </h2> 
        <%= post.title %>
        <br>
        <h2>
        <%= post.content %>
        </h2>
        <br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: wild guess... blogs is empty?  Use a debugger and check what the state of blogs is when it gets to that line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @blogs variable must contain no data; otherwise, you would be seeing at least the lines and text that you've put in.

Go into the rails console and type Blog.all and make sure that something is being returned.

On a separate note, your formatting is OK but not ideal. `<br>` is almost never necessary; you can take care of spacing issues with CSS instead of with breaks. `<h2>` and `<hr>` already break the line.

More importantly, this would be a great place to render a partial.

```
<% @blogs.each do |post| %>
  <%= render partial: "blog", locals: { post: post } %>
<% end %>
```

You would then have a corresponding _blog.html.erb file that is just

```
<hr>
<h2><%= @post.title %></h2>
<p><%= @post.content %></p>
```